# Tictac toe game keeps stopping with logcat error java.lang.IllegalStateException:Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

When I play the game it causes an error after some time and the window closes, App keep stopping.
Logcat for the game is

```
    Process: com.example.tictactoe, PID: 12663
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28309)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7698)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28309) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7698) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
    at com.example.tictactoe.MainActivity.playertap(MainActivity.java:32)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28309) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7698) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

XML Code for the game is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/heading"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/main_grid"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/grid" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/o_value"
                android:onClick="playertap"
                android:tag="1"
                android:padding="20sp"
                 />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playertap"
                android:tag="2"
                android:padding="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playertap"
                android:tag="3"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:padding="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playertap"
                android:tag="4"
                android:padding="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playertap"
                android:tag="5"
                android:padding="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playertap"
                android:tag="6"
                android:padding="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playertap"
                android:tag="7"
                android:padding="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="playertap"
                android:tag="8"
                android:padding="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick ="playertap"
                android:tag="9"
                android:padding="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15sp"
        android:text="@string/status"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
like so
```

***mainactivity java code:***

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    boolean gameActive = true;
    // Player representation
    // 0 - X
    // 1 - O
    int activePlayer = 0;
    int[] gameState = {2, 2 , 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
    //    State meanings:
    //    0 - X
    //    1 - O
    //    2 - Null
    int[][] winPositions = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8},
            {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8},
            {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};
    public void playertap(View view){
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view;
        int tappedImage = Integer.parseInt(img.getTag().toString());
        if(!gameActive){
            gameReset(view);
        }
        if(gameState[tappedImage] == 2) {
            gameState[tappedImage] = activePlayer;
            img.setTranslationY(-1000f);
            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                activePlayer = 1;
                TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
                status.setText("O's Turn - Tap to play");
            } else {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                activePlayer = 0;
                TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
                status.setText("X's Turn - Tap to play");
            }
            img.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(300);
        }
        // Check if any player has won
        for(int[] winPosition: winPositions){
            if(gameState[winPosition[0]] == gameState[winPosition[1]] &&
                    gameState[winPosition[1]] == gameState[winPosition[2]] &&
                    gameState[winPosition[0]]!=2){
                // Somebody has won! - Find out who!
                String winnerStr;
                gameActive = false;
                if(gameState[winPosition[0]] == 0){
                    winnerStr = "X has won";
                }
                else{
                    winnerStr = "O has won";
                }
                // Update the status bar for winner announcement
                TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
                status.setText(winnerStr);

            }



        }

    }

    public void gameReset(View view) {
        gameActive = true;
        activePlayer = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<gameState.length; i++){
            gameState[i] = 2;
        }
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7)).setImageResource(0);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8)).setImageResource(0);

        TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
        status.setText("X's Turn - Tap to play");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

The app crashes usually after one input although sometimes crashes after one whole game is completed
Unable to understand as the on-click function works fine.

Comment: The tags for your ImageViews start at 1, while your array is going to start at 0. So when you click the bottom right square, you are trying to grab index 9 from an array with indexes 0-8.


Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
    at com.example.tictactoe.MainActivity.playertap(MainActivity.java:32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is in your index, like it says in your exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
 at com.example.tictactoe.MainActivity.playertap(MainActivity.java:32)
```

Two possible solutions here. The first one, which is the better one, is to simply change tags on your images from 0 to 8, instead of 1 to 9. Another approach is to just use `- 1` on `tappedImage` so you always get the right index, but this can complicate things in the future so I would suggest going with the first one since you don't have much code to edit.

This happens because when you click on `ImageView` with `tag = "9"`, `tappedImage` gets the value of `9` and you are using it as an index for your array which has a `size == 9`. But array index is always starting with `0` and going to `size - 1`. In this case, with `size == 9`, indexes would be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8` - where 8 is the last one.

As much as I can see you had that logic with your `winPositions`, you just forgot to start tags from zero.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens. Happy coding! @Arjun_Code164

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you exactly what is happening in the stack trace:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
> at com.example.tictactoe.MainActivity.playertap(MainActivity.java:32)

Line 32 of your `MainActivity` is going out of bounds of the array, and throwing an exception (`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`). Unlike the `ImageView`s which start with an index of 1, the array is 0 based indexed.

You need to adjust your array indexes so they are in the range of `0-8` instead of `1-9`, by using `tappedImage - 1`

Comment: Just did it and the app runs fine! Thank you!!